# adding api routes for roles and permssions to existing lavarel lumen project

Tags: laravel, api, permissions, roles, lumen

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

this is my users model file...

```
<?php

/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

// use Users\Http\Controllers\UserController;

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    // return $router->app->version();
    return ENV('APP_NAME');
});

$router->get('/key', function() {
    return \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(32);
});

// API route group
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    // Matches "/api/register
    $router->post('register', 'UserController@register');

    // Matches "/api/login
    $router->post('login','Users\Http\Controllers\UserController@login');

    // User Details
    $router->get('user-detail/{id}', 'Users\Http\Controllers\UserController@show');

    // Users
    $router->get('users', 'Users\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');

    // Branches
    $router->get('branches', 'Settings\Http\Controllers\BranchesController@index');

    // Branch Details
    $router->post('branch-detail', 'Settings\Http\Controllers\BranchesController@show');

    // Orders
    $router->get('orders', 'Orders\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@index');

    // Order Details
    $router->post('order-details', 'Orders\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@show');

    // Order Create
    $router->post('make-new-order', 'Orders\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@create');

    // Order Tracking
    $router->post('tracking', 'Orders\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@tracking');

    // Get Delivery Cost
    $router->post('delivery-cost', 'Settings\Http\Controllers\DeliveryController@delivery_cost');


 });
```

this is my web.php file in which I want to add routes.

I added roles and permissions to an existing lumen project using https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-lumen. Now I wanted to add the option for the roles and permissions to be edited(removing and adding) and a way for them to be tested(need to add the routes in the web.php file). I have added Has Roles to the users model file and I'm yet to add the roles options to the users table. However, every tutorial I've found seems to be finetuned for Laravel not lumen with steps that don't see how to do in lumen like update the kernel. This https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-spatie-roles-and-permissions-tutorial-from-scratch is the link I tried to use but couldn't finish because there's files I was asked to edit that were not in lumen

Comment: Hey welcome to the stackoverflow. Please share code, not screenshot so we can help you better.

Comment: hey @gguney thank you. I've tried to edit and add the code, please let me know if there's anything I need to add. Thank you.